add a calendar icon to a datefield or not?
My question is straightforward but I don't know which is best. Should a date field have a calendar icon to communicate that the user can open up a calendar widget or has this become irrelevant because a user knows she can open a widget just by clicking on the date field? I should guess the latter but I see a lot of applications that still have it and personally I think it's a bit clearer this way, especially since the date fields have no label (but will always display a default date syntax).


I suggest you keep the calendar icon on the text field to comply with WCAG that mentions that a website must be perceivable and understandable. If you remove the icon you need to make your content understandable in any other way for people that could not understand the language that your website is or people that has a certain level of blindness (you can use html tags for that). Also, have in mind that there are two ways to format a date mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy, so you need to help your user to identify which format are you using in the site.
I'm going to leave the link so you can dive into the 2.1 version.
WCAG2.1

Thanks, I honestly didn't even think of WCAG yet :)
